# How to run a bash script automatically at gnome login

Tags: linux, gnome, centos-7, screen-recorder, profile

I want to use Gnome's inbuilt Screen Recorder for recording GUI sessions for audit purpose. To automate this, I changed the Shortcut for the screen recorder as "Alt+U" and then executed command "xdotool key Alt+U" And it is working. Now I want to run this command every time someone login to gnome. I tried to add this command 1) /etc/profile 2)/etx/xdg/autostart/new.desktop 3)added a startup application using gnome-session-properties. Nothing is working. It would be great if someone can guide me in the correct way.

Answer (score -2):

Not familiar with Gnome, among KDE control panels you can find someting like Run after Start or Automatic started applications. I hope in Gnome there must be something similar.